# Align statements on specific word in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, text-alignment

I want to align statements in WebStorm based on specific word/part of line.
Like this:

```
import React                             from 'react';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';
```

I know i can turn on assignment align in WebStorm but this is different, i need to choose manually where to split.

I saw that you can do this with Tabular plugin for vim but i need it in WS.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible currently. Similar feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7033